# Extract rows where value appears in any of multiple columns

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Let' say I have two data.frames

```
name_df = read.table(text = "player_name
a
b
c
d
e
f
g", header = T)

game_df = read.table(text = "game_id winner_name loser_name
1 a b
2 b a
3 a c
4 a d
5 b c
6 c d
7 d e
8 e f
9 f a
10 g f
11 g a
12 f e
13 a d", header = T)
```

`name_df` contains a unique list of all the `winner_name` or `loser_name` values in `game_df`. I want to create a new data.frame that has, for each person in the `name_df` a row if a given name (e.g. `a`) appears in either the `winner_name` or `loser_name` column

So I essentially want to merge `game_df` with `name_df`, but the key column (`name`) can appear in either `winner_name` or `loser_name`.

So, for just `a` and `b` the final output would look something like:

```
final_df = read.table(text = "player_name game_id winner_name loser_name
a 1 a b
a 2 b a
a 3 a c
a 4 a d
a 9 f a
a 11 g a
a 13 a d
b 1 a b
b 2 b a
b 5 b c", header = T)
```

Comment: Your description says that it should appear in either winner_name or loser_name.  then why are the otther elements not selected

Comment: Based on your description, the logic would be `game_df %>% filter(winner_name %in% name_df$player_name| loser_name %in% name_df$player_name)`

Comment: Or `game_df %>% filter(if_any(c(winner_name, loser_name), ~ . %in% name_df$player_name))`

Comment: That is also not giving the expected i.e. `map_dfr(setNames(name_df$player_name, name_df$player_name),  ~ game_df %>% filter(winner_name %in% .x|loser_name %in% .), .id = 'player_name')`

Comment: Please check your input.  The `game_df` 13th row shows 'a' for 'winner_name' but it is not included in `final_df`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can loop over the elements in 'name_df' for 'player_name', `filter` the rows from 'game_df' for either the 'winner_name' or 'loser_name'

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(setNames(name_df$player_name, name_df$player_name), 
   ~ game_df %>%
        filter(winner_name %in% .x|loser_name %in% .x), .id = 'player_name')
```

---

Or if there are many columns, use `if_any`

```
map_dfr(setNames(name_df$player_name, name_df$player_name), 
  ~ {
     nm1 <- .x
     game_df %>%
       filter(if_any(c(winner_name, loser_name), ~ . %in%  nm1))
      }, .id = 'player_name')
```

Comment: Works amazingly! I'm afraid I don't quite understand the `filter` syntax. what is `.x|` doing?

Comment: @Parseltongue the `.x` is each of the value from player_name.  it is anonymous/lambda function (`~`).  you may also write as `function(x) game_df %>% filter(winner_name %in% x|loser_name %in% x), .id = 'player_name')`

Comment: @akrun Unblievable! You learn something here and not a single day later you can use it for another question! I'm speechless and don't know how to thank you.

Comment: This is great, Akrun! On my 1.2 million row dataset, however, this never completed. Do you have a recommendation? Perhaps a data.table solution?

Comment: @Parseltongue yes, then you can use `data.table` option i..e `setDT(game_df); rbindlist(setNames(lapply(name_df$player_name, function(x) game_df[winner_name %chin% x|loser_name %chin% x]), name_df$player_name), idcol = 'player_name')`

Answer (score 4):

**Dedicated to our teacher and mentor dear @akrun**

I think we can also make use of the `add_row()` function you first taught me the other day. Unbelievable!!!

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

game_df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(player_name = winner_name) %>%
  group_split(game_id) %>%
  map_dfr(~ add_row(.x, game_id = .x$game_id, winner_name = .x$winner_name, 
                    loser_name = .x$loser_name, player_name = .x$loser_name)) %>%
  arrange(player_name) %>%
  relocate(player_name)


# A tibble: 26 x 4
   player_name game_id winner_name loser_name
   <chr>         <int> <chr>       <chr>     
 1 a                 1 a           b         
 2 a                 2 b           a         
 3 a                 3 a           c         
 4 a                 4 a           d         
 5 a                 9 f           a         
 6 a                11 g           a         
 7 a                13 a           d         
 8 b                 1 a           b         
 9 b                 2 b           a         
10 b                 5 b           c         
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Comment: fab! But I think `rowwise` is redundant here too!  Isn't it?  Or Am I missing somewhere?

Comment: @AnilGoyal Thank you thank you! I thought it would be necessary since I was about to get the initials of every `player_name` in a row but it appears it is not necessary and the code yields to the same result without it.

Answer (score 4):

This can be directly expressed in SQL:

```
library(sqldf)

sqldf("select * 
  from name_df 
  left join game_df on winner_name = player_name or loser_name = player_name")
```

Answer (score 2):

Without using `purrr`.  I think this is appropriate use case of `tidyr::unite` with argument `remove = F` where we can first unite the winners' and losers' names and then use `tidyr::separate_rows` to split new column into rows.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

game_df %>% unite(Player_name, winner_name, loser_name, remove = F, sep = ', ') %>%
  separate_rows(Player_name) %>%
  relocate(Player_name) %>%
  arrange(Player_name)

# A tibble: 26 x 4
   Player_name game_id winner_name loser_name
   <chr>         <int> <chr>       <chr>     
 1 a                 1 a           b         
 2 a                 2 b           a         
 3 a                 3 a           c         
 4 a                 4 a           d         
 5 a                 9 f           a         
 6 a                11 g           a         
 7 a                13 a           d         
 8 b                 1 a           b         
 9 b                 2 b           a         
10 b                 5 b           c         
# ... with 16 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

A Base R approach :

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(name_df$player_name, function(x) 
                   cbind(plaername = x, 
                   subset(game_df, winner_name == x | loser_name == x))))

rownames(result) <- NULL

result
#   playername game_id winner_name loser_name
#1           a       1           a          b
#2           a       2           b          a
#3           a       3           a          c
#4           a       4           a          d
#5           a       9           f          a
#6           a      11           g          a
#7           a      13           a          d
#8           b       1           a          b
#...
#...
```